# Windows 11 (or win10,win2k19) LXD 5.17 not booting

Tags: boot, windows, virtualization, lxd

I am using the 'How to install a Windows 11 VM using LXD' ubuntu tutorial.

I have tried to install windows 11 (win10 and window2k19) on LXD 5.17. On each VM boot it doesn't recognise the hard disks and ends up in UEFI shell.

Has anyone any idea of any particular LXD configurations that may be necessary?